# Missing Kafka events with 2 consumers on a Topic

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-go

Hi I have 2 consumers on a kafka topic. Both of them belong to different consumer groups but consuming from the same topic. I am using Go kafka library to consume the messages through both the consumers.

This problem only occurs when I see a number of events on this topic. for ex when 1000 events are seen on this topic for some reason one consumer is receiving around 600 and the other around 200. This number varies from time to time. In normal circumstances when there is 1 event, It is always consumed by both of them.

And I also noticed that the missing message on one consumer is seen on the other and vice versa. Though there might be messages missing on both of them as well. This eliminates the producer not producing the messages.

Is there anyway in which consumer groups get mixed up. I'm not sure what exactly is going on.

Does anyone know what's going on and how I can debug this further?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should simply not be possible with two unique consumer groups. Can you create a [mcve]? Which Kafka client are you using (have you tested this using `kafka-console-consumer`)? How are you managing offset commits? Are you manually seeking the group past records? If neither group is not getting any event, then the problem definitely exists in the producer

Comment: I’m auto commiting and reading from “earliest”. Sometimes both aren’t seeing it, sometimes one is seeing it and it works most of the time. This seems to be a rare scenario.

Comment: Again, which go client library are you using? And can you show a [mcve]? Have you tried filling an issue with that library?

Comment: I'm using this library "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka" . I haven't yet. I'm not sure if there is problem with Kafka library or my code or the Kafka itself. There also might be some problem how message is being produced. I'm not sure what to look into next. Where do you think the problem could be? I'll try to get in a reproducible example but this problem state is not always seen. It's a rare scenario. for lower message count like 50-100 this always works fine.

Comment: If you show your code, then we should be able to tell you if the problem is there or not.